# .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)) adds unwanted padding to my view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm attempting to build a Tabview where I can use swipe gestures to access the different tab item destinations.

This works using

```
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

however, it leaves my views with unwanted padding.

I've tried using

```
   .ignoresSafeArea()
```

but it still doesn't change the unwanted padding, a pic of that is below:

[seen clearly by the blue background on the top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ydZD.png)

my code is below:

```
        ZStack {
            Color(hex: "17203A").ignoresSafeArea()
            
            SideMenu()
                .padding(.top, 50)
                .opacity(isOpen ? 1 : 0)
                .offset(x: isOpen ? 0 : -300)
                .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(isOpen ? 0 : 30), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
            
            TabView {
                HomeView()
                    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                        Color.clear.frame(height: 80)
                    }
                    .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
                        Color.clear.frame(height: 104)
                    }
                    .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(isOpen ? 30 : 0), axis: (x: 0, y: -1, z: 0),               perspective: 1)
                    .offset(x: isOpen ? 265 : 0)
                    .scaleEffect(isOpen ? 0.9 : 1)
                    .scaleEffect(show ? 0.92 : 1)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know where to place view modifiers in SwiftUI, and in this case I assume you tried to make the TabView ignore safe area directly. This is almost correct, but not quite.

To get the parent ZStack to ignore the child TabView padding, you need to place the `.ignoresSafeArea()` view modifier at the end of the ZStack like this:

```swift
ZStack {
  ...
  TabView {
    ...
  }
  .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
  //.ignoresSafeArea() ❌
}
.ignoresSafeArea() ✅
```